# Apache with mod_authnz_external giving blank password

Tags: authentication, apache2

I am using apache2 with mod_authnz_external and pwauth for authentication. pwauth itself works (I verified by calling it from the command line), however when used by apache, I always get error code 2 back (password mismatch).
By using a wrapper around pwauth and calling strace on it, I narrowed the problem down: it seems like apache is not piping the password to pwauth.

In my trace I get

```
read(0, "user\n\n", 1024)
```

while I would expect

```
read(0, "user\npassword\n", 1024)
```

(which I DO get on another system where it's working).

Does anybody have a clue what's causing this?

Apache version on broken system: `2.4.46`,
Apache version on working system: `2.4.18`.
Config is nearly identical on both systems.